# Кэширование данных после парсинга (memcache) | PHP

Tags: php, memcached

Приветствую всех.

Есть парсер, который берет информацию с определенного сайта и записывает в массив:

```
foreach($html->find('#index') as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key]['date'] = pq($value)->find('td:eq(0)')->text(); 
    $result[$key]['name'] = pq($value)->find('a:eq(2)')->text();
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это все дело записать в memcache и проверить, имеется ли информация в кэше или нет? Количество итераций - более 150. (С memcache еще не разобрался)

Answer (score 1):

Не пойму, в чем сложность? Вам не понятно, как работает метод [`Memcache::add()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/memcache.add.php)

Установили соединение с сервером memcached и вызываете этот самый метод

```
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect("localhost", 11211);
$memcache_obj->add('site1_data', $result, false, 0);
```

Для каждого набора данных генерируете уникальное имя.

По идее данные будут сериализованы, и потом сохранены. Чтобы самому "контролировать процесс", может использовать перед сохранением функцию [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php), а после получения методом [`get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/memcache.get.php) - соответственно [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php)